# Can a particle fish another out of the event horizon of a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

Suppose a massive charged particle flies along a trajectory that escapes to infinity by a stationary neutral black hole with mass $M$ which exhibits the Schwarzschild metric. That means the perigee of the trajectory of this particle is greater than $1.5r_S$ where $r_S=2GM$ is the Schwarzschild radius and $G$ is the gravitational constant with the speed of light set at unity. Another much lighter oppositely charged particle flies into the event horizon of the black hole. How do the two charged particles interact with each other electromagnetically? Because the second charged particle is moving in the metric formed by both the gravity of the system consisting of the black hole and the electrostatic or electromagnetic field of the first charged particle, the net/combined event horizon of the system could be different from the static event horizon of the otherwise solitary black hole which is at $r_S$ as defined earlier. Here is the question: Is there a trajectory that the lighter particle can take that would allow it to first enter $r_S$ then emerge out of $r_S$?

[The equation of motion of a single particle moving around a Schwarzschild black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Mathematical_derivations_of_the_orbital_equation) does not seem to immediately reject the prospect of escape for the lighter particle.

Comment: Not only can it not escape but the outer particle cannot even sense the electrical charge of the particle inside, because that would require the electromagnetic field to travel from inside to outside the horizon, which cannot happen.

Comment: @RC_23 I don't think that's correct, because there is an electric field associated with the charge of a black hole in the [Reissner-Nordstrom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric) metric. (In QFT language, photons mediating the electrostatic interaction are off shell, so don't have a speed per se).

Comment: Yes you're right, I was mistaken.  Though obviously the inner particle still cannot escape.

Comment: @RC_23: Can you show your reasoning?

Comment: The inner particle can never escape because once inside the horizon, "radially outward" is no longer an available direction for it, as the answer with the Penrose diagram shows. But as it falls in to begin with, its charge has a lasting effect on the EM field lines outside the BH that remains, due to Gauss's law, giving the BH a net charge.  This the BH can attract charged particles or be attracted itself, but never be "pulled back apart" into constituent parts.

Comment: @RC_23: It just begs the question whether $r_S:=2GM$ is the (combined) event horizon of the system of the black hole and the first (heavier) charged particle. Would the charged particle dent the original event horizon $r_S:=2GM$ produced by the lone black hole?

Comment: It would be great if the down-voters would air their objections to the question explicitly.

Comment: The other bodies will dent the horizon, but that doesn't allow anything already behind it to escape. For the details of the bending (although for the uncharged case, but gravitational and electromagnetic waves travel with the same speed anyway) see [MTW, Box 32.2](https://i.imgur.com/Q9s6jaE.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is useful to consider the Penrose diagram for a Schwarzschild black hole, which lets us see the causal structure (I took this figure from here: https://online.kitp.ucsb.edu/online/colloq/hamilton1/)

[image]

The Penrose diagram represents the entire black hole spacetime (we'll only consider the "physical" parts of the black hole that can form due to collapse, and ignore two other regions of this spacetime that exist mathematically for an external Schwarzschild solution but are not physically relevant). The key property of this diagram is that light travels on 45 degree lines.

The blue line represents a particle that falls into the black hole. Once the particle crosses the horizon, all 45 degree lines that emanate from the particle hit the black hole singularity (the $r=0$ curvy line at the top of the diagram). None of them make it to the diagonal $r=\infty$ line on the right side of the diagram.

Therefore, in order to escape the horizon, the particle would need to move on a line steeper than 45 degrees -- or in other words, move faster than light. Nothing -- not even an electrical attraction to a particle outside the black hole -- can make a particle travel faster than light, within standard physics.

Therefore, a charged particle cannot fish another charged particle from beyond the horizon.

Comment: The diagram is formed after the metric and therefore the event horizon is determined. The question is whether the metric (or a free falling trajectory) is unperturbed by the presence of a strongly charged particle; more specifically, whether a strongly charged particle dents the original event horizon $r=2GM$ of the otherwise lone presence of the black hole.

Comment: @Hans I see, indeed I was thinking that a "particle" would have a small mass compared to the black hole. The situation you are imagining is much more complicated and you would need a numerical simulation to answer it. There are also a few questions you'd have to answer, like (a) what would the analogue of the Schwarzschild radius even be in such a spacetime, which is highly dynamic (ie, at what point would you say "fishing" occurred as opposed to just deflecting a particle), (b) is the electrostatic or gravitational interactions more important for any "fishing" effects.

Comment: Yes. I was just wondering if any qualitative answer existed. The first charged particle can have a small mass compared to the black hole but the charges could be large. The electrostatic or even electromagnetic interaction between the two charged particles could be large. The net metric is formed by both the gravity and the electrostatic or electromagnetic field. Yes, it would be dynamic. The Schwarzschild radius $r_S$ is *defined* to be $2GM$ though it  has lost its special meaning in this situation. l My original question is whether the second particle can first be $<r_S$ and then $>r_S$.

Comment: If I am allowed to be greedier, I would ask if the second charged particle can eventually move to infinity in space.

Answer (score -1):

He can't get dragged out, since for that you'd need more than infinite force, while your charge can only deliver a finite force. You can only alter the speed of the infalling particle (that can be between c and ∞ in the direction of the singularity, where v=∞ is actually the slowest since light is always fastest), but not the radial direction.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141591/discussion-on-answer-by-yukterez-can-a-particle-fish-another-out-of-the-event-ho).

Comment: Why is the finiteness of the electric force not enough to perturb the metric or change the trajectory of the second lighter charged particle in the region $r<r_S:=2GM$? If the electric field does change the metric, why is it that once the second particle enters $r_S$ even with whatever speed and direction, it still will not reemerge from within $r_S$? You have not explained none of these at all.